# '"UTF-8"' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: vb.net, httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` to make a post request in Visual Basic, and one the customers get the next Error:
System.ArgumentException: '"UTF-8"' is not a supported encoding name

to read the response I use HttpResponseMessage.

I'm lost

Comment: It is the kind of problem that the customer's IT staff needs to fix.  Reinstalling .NET might repair it, but this kind of problem is rarely isolated.  Replacing the machine is always the quick and more reliable fix for disk damage.

Comment: excellent. please make it as an answer, and i will mark it.